# Tensorflow foolbox model restoring type error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting a `TypeError: input must be a dictionary` error when I am trying to restore a model into a foolbox model. I am not sure what this error is referring to or how to fix it because I don't understand the error. I was trying to follow the code posted [here](https://github.com/bethgelab/foolbox/issues/12)

the expextion was throwing at line 25:

`model.session.run( model.session, "/tmp/models/convnet_maxpool.ckpt" )`

here is the code I was using:

```
import foolbox
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, 784))
logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs, 10)

init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()

np.random.seed(2)
W = np.random.rand(784, 10).astype(np.float32)

assign_op = tf.assign(tf.global_variables()[0], W)

np.random.seed(22)
example_input = np.random.rand(784)

with foolbox.models.TensorFlowModel(inputs, logits, (0, 1)) as model:
    attack = foolbox.attacks.FGSM(model)

    model.session.run(init_op)
    model.session.run( model.session, "/tmp/models/convnet_maxpool.ckpt" )  # replace with restorer
    example_label = np.argmax(model.predictions(example_input))
    print(example_label)

    adversarial = attack(example_input, example_label, unpack=False)
    print(np.argmax(model.predictions(adversarial.image)))

    print(adversarial.distance)
```

is this error because I was restoring incorrectly or because I am doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, the following is correct:

```
saver.restore(model.session, "/tmp/models/convnet_maxpool.ckpt")
```

instead of your one:

```
model.session.run( saver.restore(tf.Session(),  "/tmp/models/convnet_maxpool.ckpt" ) )
```